# Use OWASP ZAP import URLs addon programatically and change the HTTP method

Tags: owasp, zap

I was thinking of using this functionality in my script, but it seems that importing URL file automatically sets GET method for every URL on the list, so when Active Scan is run, it only performs GET requests for this URLs. I know I can change the method manually with *resend* option, but I'm implementing tests to be run automatically with CI, so it's not an option. Is it possible to change all the request's method  in history with one zaproxy method?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an HttpSender script that sonverts the request, the enable it before importing the URLs and disable is afterwards. There are example scripts here: https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/master/httpsender 
Please submit any new ones you develop if you think anyone else could find them useful.